# Any form of Google Search API available for C#?

Tags: c#, api, search

I know there was an API for C#, but I don't think there is any longer? Is there any way I can search Google, then load each URL into a separate item in a listbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the custom search API from C#: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: Be very careful with this.  Note the restriction of "100 queries per day".  That isn't exactly a lot.  On that note, a couple years ago we had a sys admin that was testing a tool against google.com.  An hour after he started the entire company was shut off from accessing google...  I think he did a bit more than 100 queries. ;)

Comment: 100 queries a day for free- if you choose to pay for it, you can run any number, of course.  $5 for 1000/day, up to 10000.

Comment: This'll work for me, however I was hoping to be able to do more queries. Thanks anyways!