# Extracting a URL of an image from Google search result page

Tags: c#, html, regex

Google has added a nice feature which makes you get instant info about any of famous people, for example when you search for "**Barack Obama**" you get a bio and a photo on the results page so you may not have to visit any of the results to get that info.

Live sample :  http://goo.gl/vf1ti3

What I'm trying to do is to get the URL of the image at the left-side of instant info box. I want to accomplish that using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` from the HTML code.

I can get the source of the result page with this code :

```
private void getInfoAboutCelebrities()
{
    try
    {
        string celebrityName = null;

        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            DisableUI();
            celebrityName = celebrityName_textBox.Text;
        });

        celebrityName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(celebrityName);
        string queryURL = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + celebrityName + "+Height&safe=active&oq=" + celebrityName + "+Height&gs_l=heirloom-serp.12...0.0.0.3140.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac..24.heirloom-serp..0.0.0.hXJwfydNFhk";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(queryURL);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
        request.Method = "GET";
        // make request for web page
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader htmlSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string htmlStringSource = string.Empty;
        htmlStringSource = htmlSource.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        // Extracting height
        var regex = new Regex(@"<span class=""kno-a-v"">(.*?)</span>");
        var match = regex.Match(htmlStringSource);
        var result = match.Groups[1].Value;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Extracting photo ( which I couldn't do it
        regex = new Regex(@"data:image/jpeg;base64(.*?)\x3d\x3d");
        match = regex.Match(htmlStringSource);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no such entry.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                preloader_Image.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            });
        }
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)EnableUI);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

---

Can anyone tell me what **Regular Expression** I should use? ( Because actually I can't even get the URL myself with viewing the source code! )

Comment: You'll get the classical answer Don't use Regex to parse html (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418) and use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: They always say the same, but I don't need to do a lot of stuff with the HTML code, so Regex would be the best choice for me.

Comment: But You can't get your best choice work. So why don't you give it a try. Learning curve is not much steep.

Comment: If I could extract both ( height I extract using Regex and the URL of the image ) using **HtmlAgilityPack**, then it would be great! But I couldn't figure out how to work with it. And that image seems to be impossible to get, when I view the source I can't really find it's URL there.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite likely that the image URL isn't even in the HTML that you get back. There's a whole lot of Javascript on that page. The page is intended to be viewed in a browser, which can run the Javascript and download images, format the page, etc. There's no guarantee that the information displayed is available in the HTML.

I suspect, however, that the image you're looking for is the embedded image that's base64 encoded near the end of the file. Search for `imgthumb13`, and you'll find it. Probably you can convert that to binary and then decode the image. If you know the image format. (No, I don't.)

Google's results pages are not at all designed to be read by bots or scrapers. And in fact Google frowns on you using a scraper to read their results pages. If they determine that you're using a scraper on their pages, they'll block you. If you want to process Google search results, then you should be using the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/).

Also see [Any form of Google Search API available for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6810913/56778).

One other thing. Google is continually changing the format of their search results pages. Even when the pages *look* the same, the internal structure can be much different. You'll find that the code you write to scrape today's search results pages is likely to break next month. I learned that one the hard way.

Comment: +1 for "You'll find that the code you write to scrape today's search results pages is likely to break next month. I learned that one the hard way."